# Obtaining a list of links (the actual URL) from an entire website

Tags: list

Please bear with me, I'm not a techie!

I have a website (1000s of pages) and need to get a list of links which appear on each webpage.  For example, on a page (eg, www.domain.com/reports) there may be a link 'Click here to see the report' which links to a url www.domain.com/document1 and a link 'Click to see the other report' which links to a url www.domain.com/document2.  So what I would need is a list showing:

Webpage:                   URL links:
www.domain.com/reports     www.domain.com/document1, www.domain.com/document2

There's 1000s of webpages and numerous links on each page so a manual job would take a very very long tim.

Is there any way of getting such a list, for example, using Google?

Thanks everyone for your help.

Craig

Comment: What you need is a spider , example spiderzilla or ruby's spidr.

Answer (score 0):

[Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) is the free program I use to do this.  You give it a starting url, and then it will recursively download all of the linked pages.  The output is a report that tells you all of the links and images on the site.

Comment: Great thanks for the replies.  Does anyone know of any online/web-based programs (got restrictions on downloads/running .exe files on the PC I'm currently using).

Comment: If you search at Google for "site:your_domain.com", you can see all of the links that Google has found on that site.  It won't be perfect, but it might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately site:your_domain.com doesn't provide me with a list of URL links on each page.  It's good for providing me with all the pages, but not the links on each particular page.  For example, what I'm looking for is a list of each webpage (eg, xyz.com) and then a list of URL links which appear on that particular page (eg, xyz.com/home, xyz.com/products/contact-us, bbc.co.uk, google.co.uk, etc).